# full table scan in snowflake when using order by and limit by cluster key

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Snowflake table with around 450M rows, the table contains only 2 fields, _date which is DATE type and Data which is VARIANT type. the cluster key is Date and the events are ~equally distributed around each day

| Name | LINEAR(_DATE) | rows | bytes | automation clustering |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATEDEVENTS | LINEAR(_DATE) | 444,087,723 | 129228379136 | ON |

I'm trying to run the following simple query

```
select *
from datedevents 
order by _DATE
limit 200
```

[image]

snowflake is doing a full table scan,
I can't just query first day second day, etc.' because the use case is more complicated,
But why can't snowflake use his cluster key to perform this operation efficiently and don't scan all the data? I would except it to go through the first date, second date etc' until he fulfilled the 200 limit

Comment: one answer might be that your clustering is not 100%, thus the "other partitions" are needed. This could be tested with adding a `EXPLAIN` and `WHERE _date > <minus N days>` and then looking at how many partitions would get read. and check some values of N as 1,2,7,14

Comment: Another answer might be that the optimizer for partitions loading is purely based on WHERE clauses, of which you have none, so all partitions are loaded. Again for this assumption, I would totally put an filtered limit of a N days, if you know you have X messages a day like 10x or 15x to "just be safe".

Comment: See my updated answer, that solves with pruning with `in()`

Answer (score 2):

### Update with a great fix

Ok, there's a way to get good pruning with one query.

Setup:

```sql
create or replace transient table test_prune
cluster by (creation_date)
as
select creation_date, body
from temp.public.stackoverflow_posts
```

Slow query:

```sql
select *
from test_prune
order by creation_date
limit 10
-- 10s on a S-WH
```

Fast query:

```sql
select *
from test_prune
where creation_date in (select creation_date from test_prune order by 1 limit 10) 
order by creation_date
limit 10

-- 0.2s on a S-WH
```

What's the difference, why is this `in` hint faster without needing the separate query here?

Well, I created a `transient` table instead of a `temp` table. The optimizer pruning works way better with more "permanent" tables.

[image]

---

### Previous answer

We will need to help the optimizer here. I created a similar table for my experiments:

```sql
create or replace temp table test_prune
cluster by (creation_date)
as
select creation_date, body
from temp.public.stackoverflow_posts
order by creation_date
```

Now let's run your query on it:

```sql
select *
from test_prune
order by creation_date
limit 10
```

As you say, this needs to be optimized:

[image]

I got the best results diving that query in two:

- First create a table with the dates you are looking for:

```sql
create or replace temp table top_dates
as 
select distinct creation_date
from (
    select creation_date 
    from test_prune
    order by creation_date
    limit 10
);  --687ms
```

- Then every other query can use those results:

```sql
select *
from test_prune
where creation_date in (select creation_date from top_dates)
order by creation_date
limit 10
;  --308ms
```

With this separation we can take the original query from 7.9s to 0.5s (0.3+0.25).

[image]

Comment: very nice thanks!
although under the hood it's still looks like he is doing table scan (although it's on much smaller data) and I guess it can be problematic with very large tables

Comment: Oh so on the first screenshot shows "partitions scanned: 1227 of 2548" on a ~1274 partitions table. That's because it scans it twice, and only the "date" query scans the whole thing, but because it's columnar and compact it's super fast. Then the heavy scan is well pruned. Pls report back your performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not disable cache first query will run as normal while the second will read from warehouse cache in which case you will get a result in milliseconds. The second query did not perform any computing... I am sceptical about these results.